# How can I compare a range of dates in two columns to find if a date exists in both or only one column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of dates, and i need to compare if the date exists in two columns:

[image]

IF E6 exist in range AK6:AK24 and E6 exists in range AL6:AL24, returns "Booth"
IF E6 exists in range AK6:AK24 only, returns "Column 1"
IF E6 exists in range AL6:AL24 only, returns "Column 2"

Answer (score 1):

So, set this up as you did not supply useful data:

```
IF(AND(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,M3:M7,0),0),IFERROR(MATCH(A1,N3:N7,0),0)),"both",IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,M3:M7,0),0)>0,"col 1",IF(IFERROR(MATCH(A1,N3:N7,0),0)>0,"col 2")))
```

[image]

For col 1 only and both:
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternative formula using `INDEX()` & `XMATCH()` with the help of `BOOLEAN LOGIC`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E7`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"Column 1","Column 2","Both"},
XMATCH(SUM(($AK$6:$AK$24=E6)+(E6=$AL$6:$AL$24)*2),{1,2,3})),"")
```

---

To Explain how the formula works look at the example screenshot:

[image]

---

Formulas in the example screenshot :

• in cell `AP7`

```
=SUM(($AK$6:$AK$24=AO7)+(AO7=$AL$6:$AL$24)*2)
```

• in cell `AQ7`

```
=XMATCH(AP7,{1,2,3})
```

• in cell `AR7`

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"Column 1","Column 2","Both"},AQ7),"")
```

---

• The `SUM()` within `XMATCH()` returns either `0` or `1` or `2` or `3` based on the `BOOLEAN LOGIC`

```
=SUM(($AK$6:$AK$24=E6)+(E6=$AL$6:$AL$24)*2)
```

---

• The `XMATCH()` returns the same position but it helps when there is no match, and hence returns `#N/A`

```
=XMATCH(SUM(($AK$6:$AK$24=E6)+(E6=$AL$6:$AL$24)*2),{1,2,3})
```

---

• Lastly we are wrapping it within `IFERROR()` to avoid errors and returns as blank while the `INDEX()` to get the desired output as needed.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"Column 1","Column 2","Both"},
XMATCH(SUM(($AK$6:$AK$24=E6)+(E6=$AL$6:$AL$24)*2),{1,2,3})),"")
```

---

Alternatively, you can also use `MATCH()` function if you don't have `XMATCH()` in your version of Excel.

```
=IFERROR(INDEX({"Column 1","Column 2","Both"},
MATCH(SUM(($AK$6:$AK$24=E6)+(E6=$AL$6:$AL$24)*2),{1,2,3},0)),"")
```

---

**Note:** Based on your excel version need to press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> when using `INDEX()` with `MATCH()`

---

However, if you are in `MS365` and want a spill effect then you can do it, with one single formula using `BYCOL()`

• Formula used in cell `E7`

```
=BYCOL(E6:AI6,LAMBDA(x,
IFERROR(INDEX({"Column 1","Column 2","Both"},
XMATCH(SUM(($AK$6:$AK$24=x)+(x=$AL$6:$AL$24)*2),{1,2,3})),"")))
```

---

[image]

---

Here is one more alternative, using the `CHOOSE()` Function with `BYCOL()`

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell `E7` --> Needs to fill right!

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(SUM((($AK$6:$AK$24=E$6)+($AL$6:$AL$24=E$6)*2)),"Column 1","Column 2","Both"),"")
```

---

Or, if you want a spill array then

```
=BYCOL(E6:AI6,LAMBDA(x,
IFERROR(CHOOSE(SUM((($AK$6:$AK$24=x)+($AL$6:$AL$24=x)*2)),
"Column 1","Column 2","Both"),"")))
```

---

Few Test Cases for the above formula is working as per the requirements:

[image]

---

• in cell `AS7`

```
=IFERROR(CHOOSE(SUM((($AK$6:$AK$24=AO7)+($AL$6:$AL$24=AO7)*2)),"Column 1","Column 2","Both"),"")
```

---